# How do I see a user-friendly format when debugging chrono::DateTime in vscode-lldb?

Tags: rust, lldb

The debugger shows this for `DateTime` structs:

[image]

After looking at the docs for [`lldb`](https://lldb.llvm.org/use/variable.html) to see how to format it,  I see I can format integers as hex:

```
type format add -f hex i32
```

I tried something similar for `DateTime`

```
type format add --format hex chrono::datetime::DateTime<chrono::offset::utc::Utc>
```

It's not picking up the `chrono` type even though `frame variable` shows this as the type. Even after this step is done, not sure how to parse the date to string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using @Jim Ingham hints in the other answer and a touchup to this [formula](https://github.com/intellij-rust/intellij-rust/issues/3639#issuecomment-480232986)

1. Modify the `launch.json` file by adding

```json
"initCommands": [
    "command source '${workspaceFolder}/my_type_formatters'"
]
```

2. Add the following file called `my_type_formatters` to the root of the project.

```
command script import simd.py 

type summary add -F simd.GetSummary chrono::datetime::DateTime<chrono::offset::utc::Utc>
```

3. Add a `simd.py` file to the root of the project with:

```py
from datetime import datetime,timedelta


def GetSummary(valobj, internal_dict):
    ymdf = valobj.GetChildMemberWithName('datetime').GetChildMemberWithName('date').GetChildMemberWithName('ymdf').GetValue();
    secs = valobj.GetChildMemberWithName('datetime').GetChildMemberWithName('time').GetChildMemberWithName('secs').GetValue();
    year = int(ymdf) >> 13  
    day_of_year = (int(ymdf) & 8191) >> 4;
    date = datetime(year -1, 12, 31) + timedelta(days=day_of_year) + timedelta(seconds=int(secs))
    return date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

lldb has three stages of customization for printing values of a given type.  The simplest is "type format" which specifies the format to use (hex, chars, etc) to display scalar entities.  The second is "type summary" which allows you to print a one-line string summary of the value.  The third is "type synthetic" which allows you to present a value as some kind of structured object (e.g. making `std::vector` look like an vector of values rather than its internal form.)

You want to add a ["type summary"](https://lldb.llvm.org/use/variable.html#summary-strings) for this type that parses the data and prints it as a human-readable string.

Comment: This was helpful, and so I was trying to use ```type summary add --python-script "height = valobj.GetChi.....``` to do the math part by using some python functions. But it  seems too limited to do anything complex. I tried doing `type summary add -F foo...` as well. But it's not working at all for me

Comment: I would certainly suggest writing your summary as a Python function rather than trying to do it inline with --python-script, the latter is annoying for anything more than a couple of lines.  But I can't tell from your comment what the problem is.  If seeing some examples would help, there are a bunch here: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/lldb/examples/summaries/.

Comment: Also remember that you can insert `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` anywhere in your function, and then when the summary is being evaluated, lldb will drop into the pdb debugger and you can step through the summary code.  That might help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: If you're still having problems, maybe ask another question of the form "Here's where I've gotten so far, why isn't this working..."